# How can I get "thor list" to list methods in ruby class

Tags: ruby, thor

I have problems listing my tasks in thor, even with the simplest program:

```
class Mytest < Thor
  desc "Hello world", "Puts 'hello world' on the console"
  def hello
    puts "Hello world"
  end
end
```

Here is the console output when i run `thor list`

```
$ thor list
mytest
------
thor mytest:world  # Puts 'hello world' on the console
```

As you can see the "hello" method name is omitted from the output.  Can you help me out please?

Thank you,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the 'desc' line to:

**desc "hello", "Puts 'hello world' on the console"**

Hope it helps.